# Dynamic scaling for tick intervals in Core Plot

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

I have a graph showing dates on 1 day intervals on the `X`-axis. This works fine, however, the tick labels tend to **overlap** each other and make it look like a mess.

By default, the major tick interval is set to `one day`. I would like it to scale with the rest of the graph, i.e. when I scale back enough, the major tick interval would be set to `one  week`, `one month`, etc.

How would I go on implementing this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way yet to do this automatically. The best solution would be to use a plot space delegate to monitor changes to the plot space range and adjust the labeling as needed based on the current range.

Comment: This was indeed the way to go. Thank you!